# Is it safe to free SSL_CTX after creating SSL

Tags: ssl, openssl

I'm implementing a server that can reload SSL certificate without restart. As a result, I need to create a new SSL_CTX to replace the old one. However, if there still exists some SSL sessions (created by former SSL_CTX), is it safe to free the old one? Or do I have to use some technique like reference counting to do so?

Comment: Its hard to say at the moment. We need to see your code, and how and when you release the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Or do I have to use some technique like reference counting to do so?

OpenSSL already uses reference counting so you don't have to implement your own. SSL_CTX_free just decreases the reference counter and only frees the memory if no object is still using this CTX. From the [documentation of SSL_CTX_free](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.1/ssl/SSL_CTX_free.html):

> SSL_CTX_free() decrements the reference count of ctx, and removes the SSL_CTX object pointed to by ctx and frees up the allocated memory if the the reference count has reached 0.
>   It also calls the free()ing procedures for indirectly affected items, if applicable: the session cache, the list of ciphers, the list of Client CAs, the certificates and keys.

Comment: Thanks. This is really convenient as OpenSSL already did the job for me.